# angular ng2-chart: Want to remove label from doughnut chart and want to show it outside with arrow

Tags: angular, ng2-charts

maybe it is a very silly question, but I am seriously geting stucked on this. I am using angular ng2-chart in my project and in one of the pages, I have implemented doughnut chart and to display the label on the doughnut, I have used 'chart.piecelabel.js' plugin and installed via npm.

Now I want remove the labels from doughnut and want to show outside of doughnut with arrow, so I have uninstalled that plugin, but those label on the doughnut chart is still showing.

Can anybody please help me, how to remove those labels from the doughnut chart.

My ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ChartType } from 'chart.js';
import { MultiDataSet, Label } from 'ng2-charts';
// import 'chart.piecelabel.js';
import { BsModalService, BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { AttritionModalContentComponent } from '../../attrition-modal-content/attrition-modal-content.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-commo-doughnut-chart',
  templateUrl: './commo-doughnut-chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./commo-doughnut-chart.component.css']
})
export class CommoDoughnutChartComponent implements OnInit {
  chartFilterValue: string;
  bsModalRef: BsModalRef;
  constructor(private modalService: BsModalService) {}

  private _chartFilter: string;
  public filtered_value;
  public select_duration;
  public from_date;
  public to_date;
  public getEmpBandList;
  public errorMsg;
  public chartFetchParameter: any;
  public chartCallFunction: any;
  public chartLabel: any;
  public attritionCountDisplay: any;
  public ss: any;
  public modal_content_part = 'Attrited';

  @Input() from_page: any;

  @Input() labelIds: any;
  @Input() attritionPercentage: any;

  // Doughnut
  // public doughnutChartLabels: Label[] = [];
  @Input() doughnutChartLabels: Label[];
  @Input() attritionCount: any;

  // public doughnutChartData: MultiDataSet = [[5, 8, 3]];
  @Input() doughnutChartData: MultiDataSet = [];
  public doughnutChartType: ChartType = 'doughnut';

  public doughnutChartOptions: any = {
    cutoutPercentage: 55,
    responsive: true,
    /*position: 'outside',
    pieceLabel: {
      render: 'label'
    },*/
    tooltips: {
      // Disable the on-canvas tooltip
      enabled: true,
      callbacks: {
        title: (tooltipItem, data) => {
          var tooltipLabel = data['labels'][tooltipItem[0]['index']];

          if (tooltipLabel !== null) {
            return tooltipLabel.toUpperCase();
          } else {
            return '';
          }
        },
        label: (tooltipItem, data) => {
          var allData = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data;
          var tooltipLabel = data.labels[tooltipItem.index];
          var tooltipData = allData[tooltipItem.index];
          var total_attritions: number = 0;
          // tslint:disable-next-line: forin
          for (let i in allData) {
            total_attritions = total_attritions + Number(allData[i]);
          }
          /*let tooltipPercentage = Math.round(
            (Number(tooltipData) / total_attritions) * 100
          );*/
          let tooltipPercentage = (
            (Number(tooltipData) / total_attritions) *
            100
          ).toFixed(2);

          if (this.from_page === 'absent') {
            let tooltipPercentageFormat = this.getAbsentPercentage(
              tooltipItem.index
            );
            return [
              ' Absent Count : ' + tooltipData,
              ' Absent Percentage : ' + tooltipPercentageFormat + '%',
              ' Total Absent : ' + total_attritions
            ];
          } else {
            let tooltipPercentageFormat = this.getAttritionPercentage(
              tooltipPercentage
            ).toFixed(2);
            return [
              ' Attrition Count : ' + tooltipData,
              ' Attrition Percentage : ' + tooltipPercentageFormat + '%',
              ' Total Attritions : ' + total_attritions
            ];
          }
        }
      },
      titleFontSize: 18
    },
    legend: {
      display: true,
      position: 'bottom',
      fullWidth: false,
      labels: {
        padding: 15,
        fontSize: 13,
        usePointStyle: true,
        fontColor: 'rgb(143, 142, 142)',
        boxWidth: 10
      }
    }
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        font: {
          weight: 'bold',
          size: 19
        }
      }
    }
  };

  get chartFilter(): any {
    return this._chartFilter;
  }

  @Input()
  set chartFilter(value: any) {
    //console.log('value===', value);
    this.filtered_value = value[0].filter_name;
    this.select_duration = value[1].select_duration;
    this.from_date = value[2].from_date;
    this.to_date = value[3].to_date;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.attritionCountDisplay = this.attritionCount;
  }

  public getCount(index) {
    return this.attritionCount[index];
  }

  public getAttritionPercentage(attri_perc) {
    let calculated_perc = (attri_perc * this.attritionPercentage) / 100;
    return calculated_perc;
  }

  public getAbsentPercentage(index) {
    return this.attritionPercentage[index];
  }

  public chartClicked(e: any): void {

  }


  public chartHovered(e: any): void {

  }
}
```

my html file:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <div style="display: block">
      <canvas
        baseChart
        height="400"
        [data]="doughnutChartData"
        [labels]="doughnutChartLabels"
        [chartType]="doughnutChartType"
        [options]="doughnutChartOptions"
        (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"
        (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
      >
      </canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The doughnut image of my page: [image: The doughnut image of my page]

I want to achieve my doughnut chart like below.

[image: I want to achieve my doughnut chart like below]

Can anybody, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

replace your below code portion

```
plugins: {
  datalabels: {
    font: {
      weight: 'bold',
      size: 19
    }
  }
}
```

with

```
plugins: {
  datalabels: {
    formatter: () => {
      return null;
    },
  },
}
```

Hope it will work for you. This way works for me.

Answer (score -1):

you have labels setted as doughnutchartLabels, so you should just set it as true in your ts file, as...

> `doughnutChartLabels = true;`

***instead of***

> `@Input() doughnutChartLabels: Label[];`